# Add on domain Zend framework

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I have an add-on domain named: energocertif.ro, my main domain is clickpayro.ro

Can someone help me configure my .htaccess so I would be redirected to the public folder?
I tried:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

but it says that it can not find /public/ on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the httpd.conf file apache configuration and not your htaccess.

For example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName energocertif.ro
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

    <Directory /path/to/your/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName clickpayro.ro
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

    <Directory /path/to/your/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope to give you a good idea :)

Comment: Thank you but I don't have ssh access.

Comment: So it's in the configuration of the host you must indicate that the two domains pointing to the same directory. sorry to can't more help you...